# How to make incremental load in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have Oracle 12C source and SQL Server destination. In Fact tables I need to take a daily snapshot (not entire data) and in Dimension tables I need to take only new rows, not entire table either. Seems like it is not possible use variables in Oracle side. 
What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

**

### Taking only today's data:

**
I've had very good success using the Attunity Oracle connectors. When you use them to set up an Oracle source, you can define the source as either a Table/View name, or as a SQL query. When you do this, you can add `WHERE` conditions to your query.

The simple version of this technique would look like this:
[image]

But if you want to use a date that's not hard-coded in the query, you'll need to create an expression. It's similar, but you add an `Execute SQL Task` before your data flow, and build you dynamic sql query there and save it to a variable. Then you can use that variable to define an expression for the Oracle Source SQL query.

Using the same table as before, here's how I pull the most recent 3 months of records:
[image]

Then select your Data Flow task and look at the Properties window. Under "Misc" you should see a line for your `[Oracle Source].[SqlCommand]`. You can go into the expression editor here and set your variable as the SqlCommand.
[image]

### Taking only updated rows:

For this you can employ a technique that compares hash values from your source to those in the destination to determine if a row has changed.

The first thing you need to do is import all of your data, while including a hash of the row data.

Define your Oracle Source to use a SQL Command as the Data Access mode. Here's an example with my table:

```
SELECT
CAST("Data Source Code" AS VARCHAR2(3)) AS "DataSourceCode"  
,"Matrix Id" AS "MatrixId"
,CAST("Primary Matrix Type" AS VARCHAR2(11)) AS "PrimaryMatrixType"  
,CAST("Branch Number" AS VARCHAR2(4)) AS "BranchId"
,"Effective Date" AS "EffectiveDate"
,"Expiration Date" AS "ExpirationDate"
,"Spa Flag" AS "SpaFlag"
,CAST("Default Contract Number" AS VARCHAR2(50)) AS "DefaultContractNumber"
,CAST("Direct Contract Number" AS VARCHAR2(50)) AS "DirectContractNumber"
,"Refresh Date" AS "RefreshDate"
,CAST(UPPER(RAWTOHEX(SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string =>
    CAST("Data Source Code" AS VARCHAR2(3)) || '|' ||
    "Matrix Id" || '|' ||
    CAST("Primary Matrix Type" AS VARCHAR2(11)) || '|' ||
    CAST("Branch Number" AS VARCHAR2(4)) || '|' ||
    CAST("Effective Date" AS VARCHAR2(30)) || '|' ||
    CAST("Expiration Date" AS VARCHAR2(30)) || '|'||
    "Spa Flag" || '|' ||
    CAST("Default Contract Number" AS VARCHAR2(50)) || '|' ||
    CAST("Direct Contract Number" AS VARCHAR2(50))
))) AS VARCHAR2(32)) AS "HashVal"
FROM DWDIGITAL.CONTRACT_TABLE
WHERE "Effective Date" >= TO_DATE('2018/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

I'm using `SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` here to generate an MD5 hash value, using a concatenated string of all the row's column data (make sure to convert all columns to strings for the hash). I use `SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` instead of `ORA_HASH` because I have limited permissions on the Oracle server, and `SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` doesn't need escalated privileges like `ORA_HASH` does. I also choose MD5 here because if I need to generate a hash value on the SQL side, after the fact, I can still generate the same hash values since SQL Server can also use the MD5 algorithm. If you had access to `ORA_HASH` you could use one of the SHA* algorithms. Also, notice that I add `|` between each column in the hash calculation. This is so that `"My"+"text"` and `"Myt"+"ext"` will generate different hashes and prevent a false positive because `My|text` and `Myt|ext` are different.

So now you have your destination table loaded with your data, and hashes of your data. To create your iterative load, you first need to create a "cache" of keys and hash values from your destination. Add a Data Flow task, and create a source connection that points to your destination table, and pipe direct that flow into a `Cache Transform`.
[image]

The Cache Transform will be used to perform lookup transforms in the next DFT. You'll need to configure a cache file and the columns to cache.
[image]
[image]

My primary key is set to Index Position 1.

The next Data Flow will look something like this:
[image]

The source connection here will use the same query you used during the initial load above. Then you create a Lookup Transform, and add the cached HashVal as a new column.
[image]

You should have two outputs here. The "No Match" output are rows from the source where the key doesn't exist in the destination. These are new rows to be inserted. Then take the "Matched" output and point it to a "Conditional Split". The conditional Split will compare the HashVals. Matching HashVals indicate no change to the row. Unmatching HashVals indicate a record has changed. I load these records into a staging table and use a stored proc call to do the `UPDATE` operation.
[image]